# On proving $a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc \geq 2\left({b+c\over 2}-a\right)^3$.

Tags: inequality, polynomials, proof-writing, sum-of-squares-method

This problem was a "warm-up" problem by the author. Note: $a, b, c$ are non-negative numbers.
$$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc \geq 2\left({b+c\over 2}-a\right)^3$$
I tried to remove the $2$ from ${b+c\over 2}$ and got this-
$$ 4(a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc) \geq (b+c-2a)^3 $$
$$ \Rightarrow 2(a+b+c)((a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2) \geq (b+c-2a)^3 $$
But couldn't take it any further, but it looks as if Hölder's Inequality may help. And also I don't think that it is a "warm-up" problem.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: try the substitution $x = \frac{b+c}{2}$, $y = \frac{b-c}{2}$, and work in terms of $a, x, y$ instead of $a, b, c$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because $$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc-2\left(\frac{b+c}{2}-a\right)^3$$
$$=\frac{3}{4}\Big[4a^3-4(b+c)a^2+2(b^2+c^2)a+b^3-b^2c-bc^2+c^3\Big]$$
$$=\frac{3}{4}\Big[a(2a-b-c)^2+a(b-c)^2+(b+c)(b-c)^2\Big]\geqslant 0.$$
The equality occurs for $$a(2a-b-c)^2=a(b-c)^2=(b+c)(b-c)^2=0.$$

1. $a=0$.

Thus, $(b+c)(b-c)^2=0,$ which gives $b=c$.

2. $a\neq0$.

Thus, since $a(b-c)^2=0,$ we obtain $b=c$ and since $a(2a-b-c)^2=0,$

we obtain $a=b=c$.

Comment: I can see that you "brute-force" most problems, but it is difficult to see equality scenario then.

Comment: @Book Of Flames For $a=b=c$ or $b=c$ and $a=0$ of course.

Comment: How do you know that these are only cases where the equality holds? Is it a guess?

Comment: @BookOfFlames I think it just take $b=c$ (because they are symmetric) then easy see the equality cases.

Comment: @Book Of Flames I added something. See now.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I think equality holds also for $a=0$ and $b+c =0$.

Comment: @Book Of Flames If $b+c=0$ so $b=c=0$, which you saw.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Oh yes! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If $b+c<2a$ then $$LHS \geq 0 \ge RHS.$$
If $b+c \geq 2a.$ We write inequality as
$$4(a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc) \geq (b+c-2a)^3,$$
or
$$4(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca) \geq  (b+c-2a)^3.$$
Because $a+b+c = 3a+(b+c-2a) \geq b+c-2a,$ so we will show that
$$4(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)\geq (b+c-2a)^2,$$
equivalent to
$$3(b-c)^2 \geq 0.$$
Which is true. Equality holds when $ a=b=c$ or $ a=0,\,b=c.$

**Note.** We have
$$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc-{2\left(\frac{b+c}{2}-a\right)^3}$$
$$=(b-c)^2+\frac{3\,a}{2} \Big[(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2\Big] \geq 0.$$

Comment: My SOS is same.

Answer (score 4):

My first SOS is same as Nguyen Huyen. Here is my second and third.

$$\displaystyle a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc-2\left(\frac{b+c}{2}-a\right)^3$$

$$\displaystyle=\frac34 \left( b-c \right) ^{2} \left( b+c \right) +\frac34 \left( a-b
 \right) ^{2}a+\frac14\, \left( a+b-2c \right) ^{2}a+\frac12\, \left(b+c-2a \right) ^{2}a$$
$$\displaystyle =\frac34\cdot {\frac { \left( 2\,{a}^{2}-2\,ac+{b}^{2}-{c}^{2} \right) ^{2}}{2
\,a+b+c}}+{\frac {3 a\left( a+b+c \right)\left( a-b \right) ^{2} }{
2\,a+b+c}}$$

Answer (score 1):

*Using algebra.*

Consider that we look for the minimum value of
$$F=a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc -2\left({b+c\over 2}-a\right)^3$$
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial a}=3 a^2+6 \left(\frac{b+c}{2}-a\right)^2-3 b c \tag 1$$
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial b}=3b^2-3 \left(\frac{b+c}{2}-a\right)^2-3 a c\tag 2$$
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial c}=3c^2-3 \left(\frac{b+c}{2}-a\right)^2-3 a b\tag 3$$

Using $(3)$ the only possible value of $c$ is
$$c=\frac{1}{3} \left(2 \sqrt{4 a^2-a b+b^2}-2 a+b\right)\tag 4$$ Plug in $(2)$ and solve for $b$; the only possible solutions are
$$b_1=a \qquad \text{and} \qquad b_2=\frac{\sqrt{6}-1}{2}  a\tag 5$$
$$b=b_1\implies\frac{\partial F}{\partial a}=0$$

$$b=b_2\implies\frac{\partial F}{\partial a}=\frac{1}{12} \left(359-140 \sqrt{6}\right) a^2$$ which must be rejected.

So $b=a$ and $c=a$ then $a=b=c$ and $F=0\,\, \forall a >0$